# GeoAlchemy2: Extracting geo properties from a geom column

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, gis, geoalchemy2

Following the [GeoAlchemy tutorial](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm_tutorial.html), I have created an object with the following `geom` field:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class House(Base):
....
    geom = Column(Geometry('POINT', 4326))
```

When I query the object from the database, with:

```
house = database.db_session.query(House).filter_by(whatever).first()
```

I get a `House` instance with a geom column:

```
print house.geom
01e90300005cb2a79e3d6341400e396508a20a40400000000000000000

print type(question.geom)
<class 'geoalchemy2.elements.WKBElement'>
```

**How do I query the WKBElement for its latitude and longitude?** I did not find the answer in the class documentation, neither in [its source](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/geoalchemy2/elements.html#WKBElement).

Answer (score 0):

in postgres you can look up long lat information of a wkb element like so:

```
  ST_X('01e90300005cb2a79e3d6341400e396508a20a40400000000000000000') as long,
  ST_Y('01e90300005cb2a79e3d6341400e396508a20a40400000000000000000') as lat
```